# Editing *.txt file in sharepoint 2013 opens file in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, sharepoint, edit

I have a problem opening *.txt file from Sharepoint on Windows 8.1 64bit.

When I click on file, either through link or right click and then choosing Edit document, pop-up comes with question if I want read-only or edit mode, choosing either of two, file is opened in browser (it is same in IE, Chrome and FF) and of course I can't edit it.

As far as I know, *.txt file association is set to Notepad program in Windows, for .doc documents MS Word is being opened.

Also when I put link to the file in Windows Explorer file is opened in browser again, only double click on local files opens it in Notepad.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation.  The work around i found is that -> i copy the sharepoint url that comes up and then paste in file explorer.  Then it opens in notepad.

But this is annoying - i used to be able to do this just fine in Windows 7/8.1

Srinivas

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the default program associated with the file extension ".txt" is Notepad.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations

[image: Control Panel - Set association]

Comment: Yes, it is, I wanted to include screenshot like that, but can't post images. In the meantime what is happening, i chose to open library in windows explorer, and then on double click it opened it in Notepad and that is all ok, after that when I clicked on document in Sharepoint to edit it, it opened it in Notepad too, which is great, but I dont know what happened and what was changed. Now it looks like it is doing it randomly, sometimes it opens in Notepad sometimes in IE.

Comment: check the files that are still opening IE, double check the extensions again.. or check if there's any difference..